# Adicionar dados SQLITE em Java

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

Pessoal estou com um problema que não estou conseguindo resolver em JAVA.
A intenção é fazer a conexão em um database `SQLite`. Porém não estou conseguindo fazer a inserção.
Deem uma olhada no código, por favor.

```
package conexao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class ConexaoBD {
    private Connection conecta;
    public Connection getConnection(){
        //avisando que o banco q vou utilizar é sqlite
        try {
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.sqlite.JDBC());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Problemas na hora de registrar driver");
            System.err.println("Saindo...");
            System.exit(1);
        }

    //Conectando no BD
    try {
        conecta =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:estoque.sqlite");


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Impossivel se conectar no BD");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    return conecta;
}
}
```

Segunda classe :

```
package entidades;

import java.sql.Statement;

import org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import conexao.ConexaoBD;

public class Produto {
    private String descricao;
    private int estoque_minimo;
    private int estoque_maximo;


    public Produto(String descricao, int estoque_minimo, int estoque_maximo) {
        super();
        setDescricao(descricao);
        setEstoque_minimo(estoque_minimo);
        setEstoque_maximo(estoque_maximo);
        Inserir();
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }
    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }
    public int getEstoque_minimo() {
        return estoque_minimo;
    }
    public void setEstoque_minimo(int estoque_minimo) {
        this.estoque_minimo = estoque_minimo;
    }
    public int getEstoque_maximo() {
        return estoque_maximo;
    }
    public void setEstoque_maximo(int estoque_maximo) {
        this.estoque_maximo = estoque_maximo;
    }

     public void Inserir(){  
         ConexaoBD banco = new ConexaoBD();
         Connection conecta = banco.getConnection();

         //cria objeto  
         Produto p = new Produto(getDescricao(), getEstoque_minimo(), getEstoque_maximo());           
         try {      

             Statement stmt = conecta.createStatement();
             //pegando o id maximo e somar mais um para adicionar o proximo produto
             ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT MAX(id) FROM produto");
              result.next();
              int idProx = result.getInt("MAX(id)");
              idProx++;
            // System.out.println(idProx);

             //Insere o produto
             String sql = "INSERT INTO produto(id,descricao,estoque_minimo, estoque_maximo) VALUES('idProx','p.getDescricao()','p.getEstoque_minimo()','p.getEstoque_maximo()');"; 
             stmt.executeUpdate(sql);


         } catch (SQLException u) {      
             throw new RuntimeException(u);      
         }      
     } 

}
```

Interface Gráfica

```
package interface_grafica;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import java.sql.Date;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.xml.crypto.Data;
import entidades.Produto;

public class Janela extends JFrame{
/*
 JFRAME PRINCIAL
 */
private JMenuBar menuBar;
private JLabel status;
private JMenu menuProduto;
private JMenuItem addProduto, listarProduto;

/*
 * Adicao de produto
 */
private JLabel labelDescricao, labelEstoqueMin, labelEstoqueMax;
private JTextField tDescricao, tEstoqueMin, tEstoqueMax;
private JButton btnSalvar;
private JPanel telaDeAdicao;


private void addPainelProduto() {
    labelDescricao = new JLabel("Descrição");
    labelEstoqueMin = new JLabel("Estoque mínimo");
    labelEstoqueMax = new JLabel("Estoque Máximo");
    tDescricao = new JTextField(20);
    tEstoqueMin = new JTextField(10);
    tEstoqueMax = new JTextField(10);
    btnSalvar = new JButton("Salvar");

    btnSalvar.addActionListener((e)->{
        Produto produto = new Produto(tDescricao.getText(), Integer.parseInt(tEstoqueMin.getText()),
                            Integer.parseInt(tEstoqueMax.getText()));

        status.setText(produto.toString());


    });

    telaDeAdicao = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    telaDeAdicao.add(labelDescricao);
    telaDeAdicao.add(tDescricao);
    telaDeAdicao.add(labelEstoqueMin);
    telaDeAdicao.add(tEstoqueMin);
    telaDeAdicao.add(labelEstoqueMax);
    telaDeAdicao.add(tEstoqueMax);
    telaDeAdicao.add(btnSalvar);
}




private void constroiBarradeStatus() {
    status = new JLabel("Status");
    add(status, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}


private void constroiMenu() {

    menuBar = new JMenuBar();

    menuProduto = new JMenu("Produto");
    addProduto = new JMenuItem("Adicionar");
    listarProduto = new JMenuItem("Listar");

    addProduto.addActionListener((e)->{
        status.setText("Adicionando Produtos");
        add(telaDeAdicao);

    });

    listarProduto.addActionListener((e)->{

        status.setText("Listando Produtos");
        //nao implementado ainda
    });


    menuProduto.add(listarProduto);
    menuProduto.add(addProduto);
    menuBar.add(menuProduto);
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);

}

}
```

Para o produto ser adicionado eu coloquei em uma interface gráfica os campos que são passados por parâmetro após o usuário digitar e clicar em SALVAR, ou seja, os parâmetros serão passados no ActionListener do botão salvar na IG.

Não está dando certo, alguém sabe o que é?

ERRO:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
>       at org.sqlite.core.CoreStatement.(CoreStatement.java:39)
>       at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.(JDBC3Statement.java:21)
>       at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Statement.(JDBC4Statement.java:11)
>       at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.createStatement(JDBC4Connection.java:41)
>       at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.createStatement(JDBC3Connection.java:193)
>       at org.sqlite.SQLiteConfig.apply(SQLiteConfig.java:123)
>       at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.(CoreConnection.java:85)
>       at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.(JDBC3Connection.java:26)
>       at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:24)
>       at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.(SQLiteConnection.java:45)
>       at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:114)
>       at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:88)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>       at conexao.ConexaoBD.getConnection(ConexaoBD.java:25)
>       at entidades.Produto.Inserir(Produto.java:50)
>       at entidades.Produto.(Produto.java:23)
>       at entidades.Produto.Inserir(Produto.java:53)
>       at entidades.Produto.(Produto.java:23)
>       at entidades.Produto.Inserir(Produto.java:53)
>       at entidades.Produto.(Produto.java:23)

Depois disso dá um loop com isso

> at entidades.Produto.Inserir(Produto.java:53)
>
> at entidades.Produto.(Produto.java:23)

e depois de um tempo para

Comment: Ele chega a cair em algum desses `System.exit(1)` ou ele consegue criar a conexão?

Comment: Não, ele conecta normalmente, porém só não estou conseguindo inserir no banco

Comment: Qual é o erro que da?

Comment: Coloquei lá em cima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem alguns problemas no seu código que eu observei, vou explicar cada um deles.

1° Existe uma maneira de fazer todo este trabalho com apenas 1 select, basta que sua primary key tenha o atributo [AUTOINCREMENT](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html). Assim não haverá necessidade de selecionar o máximo primeiro;

2° Os métodos estão como uma string, logo eles não estão retornando nada. idProx também está na mesma situação, caso queira continuar com essa metodologia o certo seria concatenar desta forma:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO produto(id,descricao,estoque_minimo, estoque_maximo) VALUES('" + idProx + "','" + p.getDescricao() + "','" + p.getEstoque_minimo() + "','" + p.getEstoque_maximo() + "');";
```

3° Reutilizar Statements provoca alguns comportamentos estranhos, além do que a documentação aponta: ([Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html))

> By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one ResultSet object is interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated by different Statement objects. All execution methods in the Statement interface implicitly close a statment's current ResultSet object if an open one exists.

4° Usar Statement para inserir dados abre brecha para possíveis SQL injection pois é possível observar quais dados são inseridos e seus tipos, nesse caso seria melhor usar o PreparedStatment dessa forma:

```
public void inserir(){
    // Estou supondo que você seguiu a orientação de usar AUTOINCREMENT
    Connection con = getConnection();
    PreparedStatement p = con.prepareStatement("insert into produto (descricao, estoque_minimo, estoque_maximo) values (?,?,?)");
    p.setString(1, p.getDescricao());
    p.setInt(2, p.getEstoqueMinimo());
    p.setInt(3, p.getEstoqueMaximo());
    p.executeUpdate();

    // Não esqueça de fechar ResultSets, Statments e Conexões pois elas 
    // Acumulam
    p.close();
    con.close();
}
```

Usando o PreparedStatment seu código também fica mais limpo e fácil de manter.

Ainda sobre seu código, não mais na parte de SQL, você pode melhora-lo usando this no seu construtor dessa forma:

```
public Produto(String descricao, int estoque_minimo, int estoque_maximo){
    super(); // Não entendi essa chamada, é mesmo necessária?
    // Atribui o valor recebido no construtor ao atributo da classe com mesmo nome
    this.descrição = descricao; 
    this.estoque_minimo = estoque_minimo;
    this.estoque_maximo = estoque_maximo;
    Inserir();
}
```

Também pode ser legal separar Classes para conexões, inserções, atualizações e deleções no banco, assim você encontra os métodos mais facilmente pois as classes Model estariam bem definidas. No modelo atual você está misturando os conceitos de Entidade com operações nos dados.

```
SqlInsert operacao = new SqlInsert();
operacao.inserirProduto(String descricao, int estoque_minimo, int estoque_maximo);
```

Comment: Deu certo o que eu queria, valeu!

Comment: Poderia marcar a resposta como "aceita" marcando no OK abaixo das setas para cima e para baixo?